# How to upload file attribute for document in customer registration page and displayed document link in admin customer Edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, file-upload

I want to add upload document in customer registration page and display same document in admin customer account page.I have created input type file field and saved document in customer respective table but i do now know how to display this document(file field) in admin customer account page in magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

To show it in the admin customer view page first you need to decide where you want it to show, for example if you want it to be in the "Personal Information" section you would need to create your own template from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml`

Then after the Group you could add something like

```
...

<tr>
    <td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Custom File:') ?></strong></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomFile()) ?>"File Link</a></td>
</tr>

...
```